# Extract number from string and assign it to a variable

Tags: javascript

I have "385 KM" and I want to use JavaScript to remove " KM" and put the result value "385" in a variable so I can use it as a number to compare it with another number.

```
var checkDistance = result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
```

The result of the above is a number followed by " KM" and I want to keep the number only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try using [**`parseInt()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> The `parseInt()` function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified *radix* (the base in mathematical numeral systems).
>
> > If `parseInt` encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

```js
var str = "385 KM";
var num = parseInt(str);
console.log(num);
```

**OR:** You can replace all the non digits with empty string:

```js
var str = "385 KM";
var numStr = str.replace(/\D/g,'');
console.log(numStr);
```

Comment: Works Great! I saw your previous answer when you used console.log('385 KM'.split(' ')[0]); and it worked too. Do you think using parseInt(): is better? Thanks

Comment: @user1376370, yes, of course, I think `parseInt()` is better in this case:)

Comment: It's important to note that the type returned by `replace()` will be a string, whereas `parseInt` will return an integer.  Generally this won't be an issue, due to JavaScript casting, but string-typed numbers may sometimes have unexpected side effects depending on how they are used.

Comment: @Mike ... just put Number( ) around the result to convert string to number type (if that's an issue)

Comment: @TG I suppose this is a matter of preference.  In this case, I would use a unary plus `+str.replace(...)`, but I was just trying to point out that the examples are not equivalent in case Sam or another reader comes across this.